# Join Multiple Streams of Data with Pentaho DI

Tags: pentaho, kettle

New to pentaho, I am calculating multiple metrics in this job by filtering data to multiple streams.

I have validated individual stream the calculations are working fine.

Now I want to load them to target database, tried using Multiway join wasn't sure if that is the right component but it's not yielding any records.

Please suggest appropriate steps to achieve this. I have enclosed the kettle file here.

Thanks!! [DimLoad](https://drive.google.com/a/esq.com/file/d/0B0-odvYl37C1cV9PaW53Umt2Smc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Google Drive is making me request permission from you to get the file. What version of Kettle are you using?

Comment: added permission ..i am using 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got the transform. After looking at it for a while, I think the problem is that each stream that flows into the `Multiway Merge Join` will need to be sorted by the join keys. There is practically no documentation on this step, but it works the same way the regular `Merge Join` step does, just with more than two streams, and the merge join step requires sorted input.

FYI, the `Filter Rows` step is a performance killer. If you have a large input set, I'd look at pushing down that first filter into the select statement of the `Table Input`. Then split out the other rows with a `Switch/Case` instead of 13 different filter rows. You're making 13 copies if each row in the entire table.

Comment: I have tried sorting as well but produces no result, I'll take note of Switch/Case certainly felt overkill of making 13 copies was looking for an appropriate step there.

Comment: Are you sure each step upstream from the merge join is producing output? For an inner join ALL steps have to produce output, and at least one row from all 13 must have joining keys.